# Python - How to print URL using .click/selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

My code goes into a webpage, and can click on each row of the page.

I want to ultimately, open each link of each row as a new page, so I can save the URL of each page.

I cannot get the URL without Seleniums .click() (i believe), so I resorted to .click, and then get the currentURL.

This code works only for the first row, as the webpage exits the original URL.

Is there a more efficient way to print the URLS of each row?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
sam=[]
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
for x in range (1,8):
    driver.get(f'https://www.abstractsonline.com/pp8/#!/9325/presentations/endometrial/{x}')
    time.sleep(3)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    eachrow=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="results"]/li')
    for item in eachrow:
        oth = item.find_element_by_xpath(".//h1[@class='name']")
        oth.click()
        print(driver.current_url)
```

Comment: Are you trying to click on an `<h1>` tag?  If you have an `<a>` tag, you can fetch the `href` attribute from it without clicking on it.

Comment: Yes, how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h1 class="name" data-id="696" data-key="">
  <span class="title color-primary">
    <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> 
    <span class="bodyTitle">Panel Discussion</span>
  </span>
</h1>
```

Each of your elements has a data-id grab all of them and just append url

```
https://www.abstractsonline.com/pp8/#!/9325/presentation/696

https://www.abstractsonline.com/pp8/#!/9325/presentation/{}
```

You can then grab them by

```
eachrow=["https://www.abstractsonline.com/pp8/#!/9325/presentation/"+x.get_attribute('data-id') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="results"]/li//h1[@class='name']')]

for row in eachrow:
    driver.get(row)
```